# Simple random sampling variance estimate

Tags: statistics

Consider Simple Sampling with replacement.

$\displaystyle s^2= \frac{1}{n-1} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar X)^2$ an unbiased estimate for $\sigma^2$?

could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean $s^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline X )^2$

The expected value of  $s^2$ is

$E(s^2)=E\left[\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline X )^2\right]$

$=\frac{1}{n-1}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline X)^2 \right] \quad | \pm \mu$

$=\frac{1}{n-1}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n \left[(X_i-\mu)-(\overline X-\mu) \right]^2 \right] \quad$

*Removing the square from the inner bracket*

$=\frac{1}{n-1}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n \left[(X_i-\mu)^2-2(\overline X-\mu)(X_i-\mu)+(\overline X-\mu)^2 \right]\right] \quad$

$=\frac{1}{n-1}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)^2-2(\overline X-\mu)\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)+\sum_{i=1}^n(\overline X-\mu)^2 \right] \quad$

$=\frac{1}{n-1}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)^2-2(\overline X-\mu)\color{red}{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)}+n(\overline X-\mu)^2 \right] \quad$

---

*transforming the red expression*

$\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)=n\cdot \overline X-n\cdot \mu$

Thus $2(\overline X-\mu)\color{red}{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)}=2(\overline X-\mu)\cdot (n\cdot \overline X-n\cdot \mu)=2n( \overline X- \mu)^2$

---

$=\frac{1}{n-1}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)^2-2n( \overline X- \mu)^2+n(\overline X-\mu)^2 \right] \quad$

$=\frac{1}{n-1}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)^2-n( \overline X- \mu)^2\right] \quad$

$=\frac{1}{n-1}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n E\left[(X_i-\mu)^2\right]-nE\left[( \overline X- \mu)^2\right]\right] \quad$

It is $E\left[(X_i-\mu)^2\right]=\sigma^2$ and $E\left[( \overline X- \mu)^2\right]=\sigma_{\overline x}^2=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$

It is all comprehensible ? And can you finish it ?